# Why won't my MacBook work with my Raspberry Pi WiFi?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have my [Raspberry Pi setup as a WiFi router](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software), which works great! Except for one problem, my MacBook.

Connecting through my Galaxy Tab 3 Note? A-OK. Alcatel cellphone? A-OK. Chromebook? Sure thing.

Even my Roku 2, no problem.

But my MacBook? It connects to the WiFi no problem. I can even run a `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on it and connect to the server via http://172.16.1.1:8000 and that works just fine. But if I try to `ping 8.8.8.8`? Well, that's where we start running into issues.

I actually tried [running tcpdump](https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/03/16/tcpdump-is-amazing/) on my Raspberry when I started pinging `8.8.8.8` from my MacBook, but none of the ping packets showed up. I just tried pinging from a different device and packets definitely showed up.

There definitely was traffic from the Mac - a lot of UDP traffic, some TCP. Most of the TCP packets from my MacBook were retransmissions. There were *some* packets that were routed back to the IP. Here are a couple of the IPs:

**UDP:**

- `65.55.223.48,21,17`
- `64.4.23.170,148,142`
- `50.242.151.22`
- `37.59.40.88`
- `208.64.201.169`
- `162.254.199.136`

**TCP:** (only these two IPs sent any TCP packets back)

- `65.55.223.37`
- `208.64.201.169`

So for some reason it appears that my Mac, and only my Mac, isn't doing *something* right. Any clue what could be causing the connection to fail?

**Update**:

It definitely looks like a DNS issue - Google Chrome provides an error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET`. Also, I can do `telnet 216.58.218.206 80`, and then interestingly enough it waits and waits and waits, but then it connects. After which

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Content-Accept: */*
```

Returns with the Google 301 redirect to http://www.google.com

Comment: It isn't necessarily the Mac doing something wrong, you cannot conclude that yet. It sounds like the default gateway wasn't set on the Mac. Can you check to see if a default gateway is set, and if so, to which IP? If the default gateway is not set, it could indicate a problem with your dhcpd configuration on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @jksoegaard according to the instructions I found on some other site, I went to system prefs > network > advanced > tcp/ip and I found `Router: 172.16.1.1`, so I believe it's set properly. I'm updating the question with some more information that I've discovered

Comment: Looks like this is definitely a DNS issue - when I add `68.105.28.11`, which I'm *guessing* is my ISPs DNS it seems to work fine?

Comment: Sounds like your dhcpd configuration is set to send out wrong DNS-servers? what is listed for DNS in the configuration file on the rPi?

Comment: @jksoegaard see my answer - the DNS is actually fine, I guess it had something to do with the routes on the macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something was horked up with my routing table. [Flushing my routes](https://serverfault.com/questions/78365/how-to-reload-default-mac-osx-routing-table-without-rebooting) with

```
$ sudo route -n flush
```

at the terminal several times, clearing my custom DNS entries, and turning my wifi off and then on again allows me to connect properly.